# How can I resolve "out of memory" error with 'heroku run console' for 15k users, using Mongoid3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am running the following code over 15k users on 'heroku run console' and it's exceeding 512MB, how can I optimize this code to stop running out of memory???

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.authorization = 'enabled'
  user.save!
end
```

This code is modified for it's simplicity, there are a few things i do in terms of query other objects VS user.authorization = 'enabled'...i'm more wondering on how to stop the memory leak?

Comment: is this regular code? or you just want to run this once?

Comment: If there aren't any callbacks that matter just do it in the DB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`User.all` returns a lazy loaded activerecord relation*, calling `#each` on that relation causes the relation to be loaded into a collection of instantiated objects, which consumes memory in proportion to the number of users in your database.

Instead, do this

```
User.find_each do |user|
   user.authorization = 'enabled'
   user.save!
end
```

`#find_each` is an activerecord method that only instantiates one user object at a time. Furthermore, it batches the queries into sets of 1000 users, which reduces memory consumption at a given time.

* in Rails 4. In earlier Rails, `.all` loaded the results into a collection of instantiated objects.

Edit:

By the way, this one-liner will have the same effect, but in a single query and without loading any data or instantiating any objects (it's the most memory- and time-efficient solution):

```
User.update_all(authorization: 'enabled')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use Batches Instead

According to the documentation:

> Looping through a collection of records from the database (using the all method, for example) is very inefficient since it will try to instantiate all the objects at once.
>
> In that case, batch processing methods allow you to work with the records in batches, thereby greatly reducing memory consumption.

Using [ActiveRecord::Batches#find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) instead of just iterating through an array of objects with #each will generally solve this problem; if not, reduce your `:batch_size` until it fits in your available RAM.